# How to apply date filter also to columns which don't have it

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE date <= '2017-05-16 20:00:00'
```

But this doesn't find rows which don't have that column `date` filled. I want to treat them as 0000-00-00 00:00:00 so I just want my query to find those rows too. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use explicit logic:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE date <= '2017-05-16 20:00:00' OR date IS NULL;
```

I would advise you to put in an explicit default date (even `'0000-00-00'`).  It is not obvious that `NULL` means "the earliest possible date".